# MySQL (Group Min Query)

Tags: mysql

I have this table `my_table` with 3 columns as follows

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,date DATE NOT NULL
,val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(38,'2014-02-16', 3),
(38,'2014-02-17', 3),
(38,'2014-02-18', 2),
(38,'2014-02-19', 1),
(38,'2014-02-20', 3),
(38,'2014-02-21', 3),
(38,'2014-02-22', 3),
(38,'2014-02-24', 3),
(38,'2014-02-25', 3),
(38,'2014-02-26', 3),
(38,'2014-02-27', 3),
(38,'2014-02-28', 3),
(38,'2014-03-01', 3),
(38,'2014-03-02', 2),
(38,'2014-03-03', 2);
```

Is it possible to flatten/group this by a query such that the output will be

```
38, '2014-02-16', 3
38, '2014-02-18', 2
38, '2014-02-19', 1
38, '2014-02-20', 3
38, '2014-03-02', 2
```

This is puzzling me for almost 3 days now; Creating a temp table and adding trick column id for grouping didn't do me any good

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Example of SQL?
And what exactly are you trying to do? What column do you want to group by?

Comment: I guess you're looking for sequence starts and ends - that's a doozy

Comment: I have already tried the query below, and I dont just create query I look at the data and think so far, by adding autoinc id looking at it I cant find a way to sequence group it. i dont want to loop insert check it to another table coz it may have more 1000 row per process. I was thinking is there a way to some how create a "rownum with order by partition" just like in MSSql it could posible do the trick. - is mysql have done kind of feature? if thier I cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.employee_id, t1.date, t1.section_id FROM
tableA t1
LEFT JOIN tableA t2
ON t1.date = ADDDATE( t2.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE ISNULL(t2.section_id) OR t1.section_id <> t2.section_id
ORDER BY t1.date
```

This may be very inefficient though, depending on your case.

Comment: this is close, thanks but still struggling as this only considered 1 day a head. I will used this as pattern and check it I get anything. thanks. later..